# Create a sql table from two list

Tags: python, sql, list

Im trying to create a sql table:
I want to give an id to every movie title and rating and the create a tabel with 3 fields
¨

My code so fare is:

```
import re
import sqlite3
#conn = sqlite3.connect('imdb.db')
#c = conn.cursor()

#c.execute('''CREATE TABLE imdb
         (mov_id, Title, Rating)''')

x = open("ratings.list.txt","r")
movread = x.readlines()
x.close()



#s = raw_input('Search: ').lower()
for ns in movread:


    if 'the lord of the' in ns.lower():
        d = re.split('\s+',ns,4)
        Title = d[4]
        Rating= d[3]

        list = [Title,Rating]
        print list
        # Insert a row of data
#c.execute("INSERT INTO imdb VALUES %r;" %(tuple(Rating)))")
#       conn.commit()
```

My list look like this:

```
               Movie Title                                 Rating

['The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)\n', '8.9']
['The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)\n', '8.8']
['The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)\n', '8.7']
```

How can i get this into a SQL db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to insert movie id manually, change creating your imdb table definition with:

`c.execute('''CREATE TABLE imdb (mov_id ROWID, Title, Rating)''')`

which lets you omit specifying mov_id in your insert.

Then, just add your record using

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO imdb (Title, Rating) values ("%s","%s")'%(list[0],list[1]))
```

just instead of your `# Insert a row of data` line.

BTW: I'd personally do rstrip() on your Title to remove newline character, if you don't need it:

`Title = d[4].rstrip()`

Comment: where should i put the insert statment ?

Comment: @user3322871 I edited my post to answer your question. Of course remember to uncomment lines #3 and #4 to connect to your db and create a cursor used in execute insert statement.

Comment: @user3322871, yes, I corrected it. And don't forget to run conn.commit() after inserting rows to save the records to the db.

Comment: that worked but does not give me the row id like and is not printing all of them out. Im posting my code now under update

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
import re
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('imdb.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE imdb (mov_id ROWID, Title, Rating)''')

x = open("ratings.list.txt","r")
movread = x.readlines()
x.close()



#s = raw_input('Search: ').lower()
for ns in movread:


    if 'the lord of the' in ns.lower():
        d = re.split('\s+',ns,4)
        Title = d[4].rstrip()
        Rating= d[3]

        list = [Title,Rating]

    # Insert a row of data
        c.execute('INSERT INTO imdb (Title, Rating) values ("%s","%s")'%(list[0],list[1]))
        conn.commit()
        for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM imdb ORDER BY Title'):
            print row
```

Output:

```
    OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-598-0de924f55a23> in <module>()
     24 
     25         # Insert a row of data
---> 26         c.execute('INSERT INTO imdb (Title, Rating) values ("%s","%s")'%     (list[0],list[1]))
     27         conn.commit()
     28         for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM imdb ORDER BY Title'):

 OperationalError: near "5": syntax error

(None, u'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)', u'8.9')
(None, u'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)', u'8.8')
(None, u'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)', u'8.9')
(None, u'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)', u'8.8')
(None, u'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)', u'8.9')
(None, u'The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)', u'8.7')
```

Comment: you forgot to commit inserted rows, and your code indentation is wrong; c.execute should be on same indentation level as "list = [Title,Rating]" block. And, as I mentioned earlier  - you should also put "conn.commit()" after running c.execute() or database won't save your data.